# Finding a unique polynomial with particular characteristics (Hubbard Vector Calculus )

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

This is the problem 2.5.14 from Hubbard's book Vector Calculus:

Show that if $f(x) = x + \sum_{i = 2}^{k}a_i x^i$ is a polynomial, then there exists a
unique polynomial
$g(x) = x + \sum_{i = 2}^{k}b_i x^i $ with $g\circ f(x) = x + x^k+p(x)$ for some polynomial $p$.

I am trying to factorizing the term $x^{k+1}$ in composition $g\circ f;$ to do this certains conditions over coeficients of polynomials must be satisfied but I cannot see them.

Another try was comparing the compositions and dividing with a polynomial that gives monomial $x^{k+1}.$ Then, for equality between polynomials get a linear system of equations which must have unique solutions to finish this, but this seems so hard to obtain because of degree of $f$ and $g.$

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.